# Flexbox div overlaps another one in fixed container with scroll

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following elements in my component: `#bigWrapper`, that contains several elements, `#block1` and `#another`.

My task is to align vertically text in `#another` between `#block` (or other top elements in case  `#block` is not displayed) and end of the `#bigWrapper`. This task works fine.

Other task that doesn't work is : in case `#block1` and `#another` have too much content display common scroll bar for them.

I wrapped `#block1` and `#another` in `#wrapper`, but in fact `#another` overlaps `#block` content. 
It works ok when I remove `justify-content: center;` property from `#another`, but in this case 1st requirement isn't met.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#bigWrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#block1 {
  flex: 0;
}

#another {
  flex: 1 0;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigWrapper">
  <p>Some other text</p>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="block1">Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block B lock Block Block Block Block Block
      Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block B lock Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block
      Block Block Block Block Block B lock
      Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block B lock Block Block Block Block
      Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block B lock Block Block Block Block
    </div>
    <div id="another">Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another
      Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another
      Another Another Another Another Another
      Another Another Another Another Another
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/fomiwip/1/edit?html,output

Help me please - how to avoid such overlapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed `justify-content: center`, wrapper text in `#another` in `<p>` with `margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto`. Now it looks good.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#bigWrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#block1 {
  flex: 0;
}

#another {
  flex: 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#another p {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigWrapper">
  <p>Some other text</p>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="block1">Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block B lock Block Block Block Block Block
      Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block B lock Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block
      Block Block Block Block Block B lock
      Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block B lock Block Block Block Block
      Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block Block B lock Block Block Block Block
    </div>
    <div id="another"><p>Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another
      Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another Another
      Another Another Another Another Another
      Another Another Another Another Another</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```